# Handle background process while running `npm test`

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I need to perform a set of actions before and after running Mocha tests in Node.js.

- Run a script that creates the user and bot accounts on a server. This script uses an API call that creates a connection to the server and the process is not terminated after the accounts are created.
- Run the server with the account credentials created above.
- Run the Mocha tests.
- Delete the accounts created on server.

In `package.json`,

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "node createAccounts.js && (sleep 10 && mocha -t 60000 ./*spec.js); node deleteAccounts.js"
  }
```

The problem while running `npm test` is that after the tests pass, the process does not terminate. A workaround I came up with was to use `node createAccounts.js & (sleep 10 && mocha -t 60000 ./*spec.js); node deleteAccounts.js &` so that the other processes are run in the background and the tests terminate properly.

Comment: Try adding `--exit` for mocha command. Try this `mocha -t 60000 ./*spec.js --exit`

Comment: @Shrabanee If I use it in the workaround I mentioned then it has the same behaviour. If I run ps I can still see the node processes running.

Answer (score 0):

I finally settled for the below test script that runs the non-terminating processes in the background and saves the exit code in `$s`. There is just one problem: The background processes are not being terminated :(

```
"test": "node createAccounts.js & (sleep 10 && mocha -t 60000 ./*spec.js --exit) && s=0 || s=$? ; node deleteAccounts.js & sleep 5 && exit $s"
```